# HikariCP Spring + Hibernate + MySQL : Method not found: setMaxLifetime

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, hikaricp

I have trouble to set some Hikari properties into my connection.  At this point, I don't what I missed.

```
<bean id="hikariConfig" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig">
    <property name="poolName" value="springHikariCP" />
    <property name="connectionTestQuery" value="SELECT 1" />
    <property name="dataSourceClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource" />
    <property name="dataSourceProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql_demo?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull</prop>
            <prop key="user">root</prop>
            <prop key="password">admin</prop>
            <prop key="maximumPoolSize">50</prop>
            <prop key="maxLifetime">28000</prop>
            <prop key="idleTimeout">30000</prop>

            <prop key="prepStmtCacheSize">250</prop>
            <prop key="prepStmtCacheSqlLimit">2048</prop>
            <prop key="cachePrepStmts">true</prop>
            <prop key="useServerPrepStmts">true</prop>

        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <constructor-arg ref="hikariConfig" />
</bean>
```

When I set maxLifetime property, I obtain this error :

```
java.beans.IntrospectionException: Method not found: setMaxLifetime
at java.beans.PropertyDescriptor.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.PropertyBeanSetter.setProperty(PropertyBeanSetter.java:125)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.PropertyBeanSetter.setTargetFromProperties(PropertyBeanSetter.java:63)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolUtilities.initializeDataSource(PoolUtilities.java:103)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.BaseHikariPool.<init>(BaseHikariPool.java:153)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:61)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:49)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.<init>(HikariDataSource.java:78)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
```

I'm using :

Hibernate 4.3.7.Final 
and Mysql connector 5.1.21 
and HikariCP :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
    <artifactId>HikariCP-java6</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: It isn't a property of the `MysqlDataSource` which is where the properties/values in the `dataSourceProperties` are set. It is just a property of the `HikariDataSource` it self. Move it up one level as a normal property.

Comment: yes, I figure that out later :(

Answer (score 1):

I need to move property to the right place

```
<bean id="hikariConfig" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig">
        <property name="poolName" value="springHikariCP" />
        <property name="connectionTestQuery" value="SELECT 1" />
        <property name="dataSourceClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource" />
        <property name="maximumPoolSize" value="50" />
        <property name="maxLifetime" value="28000" />
        <property name="idleTimeout" value="30000" />
        <property name="dataSourceProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql_demo?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull</prop>
                <prop key="user">root</prop>
                <prop key="password">admin</prop>
                <prop key="prepStmtCacheSize">250</prop>
                <prop key="prepStmtCacheSqlLimit">2048</prop>
                <prop key="cachePrepStmts">true</prop>
                <prop key="useServerPrepStmts">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```